# Boolean values as integers from SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a "true or false" type of quiz in making. So, two buttons, one true one false, and textview with question. I have an sqlite database imported in Assets folder. 4 columns in it: _id, question, correctAnswer, wrongAnswer. Every column INTEGER except question which is TEXT. So, for every correctAnswer column I set 0 or 1, depending if the answer is true or false. But, in the game, whatever the question is I get Wrong on my left TRUE button, and Correct on my right FALSE button. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Anyway, here's the code:

```
public class Kviz extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button true,false;
    TextView question;

    LinkedList<Long> mAnsweredQuestions = new LinkedList<Long>();

    private String generateWhereClause(){
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (Long l : mAnsweredQuestions){
            result.append(" AND _ID <> " + l);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private class Answer {
        public Answer(int opt, boolean correct) {
            option = opt;
            isCorrect = correct;
        }

        int option;
        boolean isCorrect;
    }

    Runnable mLaunchTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            nextQuestion();
        }
     };

    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Answer ans = (Answer) v.getTag();
            if (ans.isCorrect) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,1200);
            }
            else{   
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,1200);
            }
        }
     };


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.kviz);

        inicijalizujVarijable();

        nextQuestion();
    }

    private void nextQuestion() {
        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        if(!myDbHelper.checkDataBase()){
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();
        }
        try{  

            mDbHelper.open(); 

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData(generateWhereClause());
            c.moveToFirst();

            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            List<Answer> labels = new ArrayList<Answer>();

            if (c.getInt(2)==1){
        labels.add(new Answer(c.getInt(2), true));
        labels.add(new Answer(c.getInt(3), false));
        tacno.setTag(labels.get(0));
        netacno.setTag(labels.get(1));

        }else{
        labels.add(new Answer(c.getInt(2), false));
        labels.add(new Answer(c.getInt(3), true));
        netacno.setTag(labels.get(0));
        tacno.setTag(labels.get(1));
        }

            true.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            false.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        }

        finally{ 
            mDbHelper.close();
        }

    }

    private void inicijalizujVarijable() {

        true = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTacno);
        false = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNetacno);
        question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPitanje);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `correct answer` column and `wrong answer` column in your database?  If they are all true/false there are only 2 possible outcomes, they get it or they don't so you could just use 1 column.

Comment: Well, I guess you are right, but that still does not solve my problem.

Comment: I need you to clarify what is happening, it does not make very much sense.  I know you are not getting the desired outcome from pressing the answer buttons but the cases of which it happens, I do not understand.

Comment: If the answer is correct I should get Taost message "Correct". Right? Well, I always get "Correct" when I press left True button, no matter what the question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make some assumptions, based on this block of code:

```
if (c.getInt(2)==1){
    labels.add(new Answer(c.getInt(2), true));
    labels.add(new Answer(c.getInt(3), false));
    tacno.setTag(labels.get(0));
    netacno.setTag(labels.get(1));
} else {
    labels.add(new Answer(c.getInt(2), false));
    labels.add(new Answer(c.getInt(3), true));
    netacno.setTag(labels.get(0));
    tacno.setTag(labels.get(1));
}
```

When `c.getInt(2)==1` is true...

- You add two answers to `labels`, so `labels[0]=true`, and `labels[1]=false`
- You set `tacno` to `true`(index 0) and `netacno` to `false`(index 1)

When `c.getInt(2)==1` is false...

- You add two answers to `labels`, so `labels[0]=false`, and `labels[1]=true`
- You set `netacno` to `false`(index 0) and `tacno` to `true`(index 1)

In both cases, `tacno` is true(correct) and `netacno` is false(incorrect). You did the flip twice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100 percent clear, but it seems to me that when you come back into the view, any old true/fals buttons that are showing on your screen, need to be updated with the value from the database, otherwise they will show as their default setting in the xml layout.